# Plot vertical lines in Gnuplot to represent one dimensional data

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot the bandwidth growth of a TCP connection using Gnuplot.

I have 2 log files, one with bandwidth at a time, and another with time stamps at which a packet drop occurs. I want to represent the packet drops in the same graph as the bandwidth, possibly with a vertical line on the X axis (time).

Please provide suggestions!

Just as a very rough example, here are the file formats.

Bandwidth.dat

```html
0.001 2
0.002 3
0.003 5
0.004 8
```

Packet_Drop.dat

```html
0.006
0.12
0.39
```

Required plot:

[image: Expected Graph]

Sorry, didn't know how to make a better graph quickly!

Comment: Please show some more information about the format of your log files (two or three examplary lines) and a sketch of how your result might look like.

Comment: Thanks! Did add information. Sorry, don't know how to do it better!

Comment: Thats enough to know what we're talking about :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As one option you could use the `impulses` plotting style, which plots vertical lines from y=0 to the given value:

```
max = 10
plot 'Bandwidth.dat' using 1:2 with lines linecolor rgb 'black',\
     'Packet_Drop.dat' using 1:(max) with impulses linecolor rgb 'red'
```

The backdraw with this option is, that you must know the maximum value of the y-axis. You can get this e.g. by plotting to the `unknown` terminal, and then use the `GPVAL_Y_MAX` value:

```
set terminal push # save current terminal
set terminal unknown
plot 'Bandwidth.dat' using 2
set terminal pop # restore terminal

plot 'Bandwidth.dat' using 1:2 with lines linecolor rgb 'black',\
     'Packet_Drop.dat' using 1:(GPVAL_Y_MAX) with impulses linecolor rgb 'red'
```

(One cannot use `stats` to get the maximum value of an *autoscaled* axis.)

Alteratively you can read in the x-values from your data file into a string and iterate over the words and set some arrows accordingly. On Linux, use

```
packet_drop = system('cat Packet_Drop.dat')
set for [w in packet_drop] arrow from first w, graph 0 to first w, graph 1 linecolor rgb 'red' nohead

plot 'Bandwidth.dat' using 1:2 with lines lc rgb 'black'
```

On Windows it should work with

```
packet_drop = system('type Packet_Drop.dat')
```

and you need to use the `wgnuplot_pipes.exe` when using version 4.6.

Comment: The first one works for me like a charm! Thanks a lot. 
Will try out others if/when I need it.